# How to use global value when reading nested maps form JSON object

Tags: json, reactjs, typescript, dictionary, nested

Hello I am reading a JSON response object like that.

```
<td className="text-right flex">
     {finance.statuses.map((statuses) => {
     return statuses.currencyAmounts.map((amounts) => (
        <span className="pr-8" key={amounts.currencyId}>{amounts.maxGambleAmount}</span>
     ));
 })}
</td>
```

Its working well, but I need to bind a currency abbreviation from global variable array behind each value with index **amounts.currencyId**, my problem is that i cannot access that currencies inside the inner map.

I try something like that currencies[amounts.currencyId], but no success.

Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: Are you actually looking for having the "currencies" globally exposed or are you able to `import` it in your current file? If having it globally available is not a requirement, just open the file where the `currencies` definition is and make sure that the variable is being exported (through `export`), then you just have to import it in your current file. TS documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import

Comment: currencies is located in mapStateToProps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your `currencies` variable is present in your `mapStateToProps` function. If there's a `mapStateToProps` it's likely that you'll be using the `redux` library. If that is the case, I would highly recommend that you invest some time getting familiar with it.

**But back to your problem**, usually the `mapStateToProps` will return an object, and all the properties of such object should be available in the `props` of your component.
If you already have the `currencies` available in your `mapStateToProps` function you could simply add it to the return statement, it would be something like this:

```js
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        // this should make your "currencies" object/map available in the props of your component:
        currencies: state.currencies,
    };
}

// In your component you should have the "props" available as the parameter,
// you just have to access it now:
<td className="text-right flex">
     {finance.statuses.map((statuses) => {
     return statuses.currencyAmounts.map((amounts) => (
        <span className="pr-8" key={props.currencies[amounts.currencyId]}>{amounts.maxGambleAmount}</span>
     ));
 })}
</td>
```